# Can you use "?" for parameters in postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This should be stupidly simple to answer, but for the life of me I cannot find a definitive answer on this.

Can you use "?" in postgres, like you can in other database engines?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = ?
```

I know I can use the $n syntax for this, for example from psql this works:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, value INT);
PREPARE bar(int) AS INSERT INTO dummy (value) VALUES ($1);
EXECUTE bar(10);
SELECT * FROM DUMMY;
```

But if I try to prepare a statement using "?", eg.

```
PREPARE bar(int) AS INSERT INTO dummy (value) VALUES (?);
```

I get:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
>   LINE 1: PREPARE bar(int) AS INSERT INTO dummy (value) VALUES (?);

...and yet, in various places I read that "postgres supports the ? syntax".

What's going on here? *Does* postgres support using ? instead of $1, $2, etc. 
If so, how do you use it?

Specifically, this is making my life a pain porting a bunch of existing sql server queries to postgres, and if I can avoid having to rewrite all the where conditions an *all of the sql statements* that would be very, very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL-level `PREPARE` in PostgreSQL does not support the `?` placeholder, it uses the `$1` ... `$n` style.

Most client libraries  support the standard placeholders used by that language in parameterized queries, eg PgJDBC uses `?` placeholders.

If you're sending your queries via a client library like nPgSQL, psqlODBC, PgJDBC, psycopg2, etc then you should be able to use the usual placeholders for that language and client.